# Where did the God Tree come from?

Tags: naruto

Ever since I finished *Naruto Shippuden*, something has always bugged me. I understand Kaguya supposedly came from a dimension of Otsutsuki warriors, but I can't just believe that the seed for the God Tree came from a random meteorite. It had to have been created by someone or something.

Is it possible to find out who created it or if it was created in *Boruto: Naruto Next Generations*?

Comment: Thanks Aki Tanaka, I don't a lot of time to fix the gramatical and capital errors.

Comment: If we're talking about "who created [thing]?" we are always gonna reach a point where you need to stop, no? Otherwise, you can always go up a level — "ok, then who created _that/them_?"

Comment: @JNat as much as I agree with you, it still would be interesting to go up a few levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Kaguya's anime backstory, we came to know that a meteorite holding the seed crashed on Earth then Kaguya appeared for then unexplained reasons.

Considering that the Boruto anime series tells us that Kaguya was sent to Earth by her clan to wait for the harvest. It could mean that either Kaguya planted the seed herself or that the seed came from a meteorite and her clan found out about it then sent her to monitor the tree.

Answer (score 1):

So from what I read, the God Tree landed on Earth from a meteorite several millennia ago. Basically landed before man kind. It also said that people were praising it like a sacred pillar from the gods but in reality it was slowly killing the earth by draining the natural chakra in the soil, rocks, water, and air. It also said that every thousand years, the God Tree produced a 'Chakra Fruit' which humans were suppose to stay away from. Members of the Otsutsuki clan searched through dimensions in search of the God Tree so they could eat the chakra fruit and obtain powerful chakra for themselves. It also said that once Kaguya Otsutsuki ate the God Tree's chakra fruit, she enslaved part of the humans population with the Infinite Tsukuyomi and bound those affected by the God Tree with it's life transforming them into White Zetsu. When Kaguya had her two sons, Hagoromo and Hamura, they were born with their own chakra, so she merged herself with the God Tree to take back their chakra and becoming the Ten-Tails itself.

I gathered this information from

http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/God_Tree